# How to check filter params from one to another params?

Tags: angularjs, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am trying to create a small filter for the page with Angular. However, I have an issue to check if the 26-35mm exists in the following brand array. So if I change the Brand Name from `All` to `G-shock` I am trying to check if the `:case_size` is available in the following filter from 26 to 35 mm, if it is not available then disable the radio button.

My product controller

```
if params[:search_brand] == "all"
  @products = @products.order('created_at ASC')
elsif params[:search_brand].present?
  @products = @products.where("brand ILIKE '%#{params[:search_brand]}%'")
  if !params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false
end
if params[:search_case] == "all"
  @products = @products.where(case_size: 0..Float::INFINITY)
end
if params[:search_case] == "26-35 mm"
  @products = @products.where(case_size: 26..35)
end
```

For example:

I have an array of brands in my filter which has a radio button option to select

```
<% @brands.each do |item| %>
  <%= radio_button_tag :search_brand,
                       item.parameterize.underscore,
                       params[:search_brand] == item.parameterize.underscore ? true : false,
                       :onchange => "window.location.assign(selectBrand(window.location, escape(this.value)));" %>
  <%= label :search_brand,
            item.parameterize.underscore %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the second part of the code

```
<%= radio_button_tag :search_case,
                     "All".parameterize.underscore,
                     true,
                     :onchange => "window.location.assign(selectCase(window.location, escape(this.value)));" %>
<%= label :search_case,
          "All".parameterize.underscore,
          class: 'menu_item__block_item' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :search_case,
                     '26-35 mm',
                     params[:search_case] == '26-35 mm' ? true : false,
                     :onchange => "window.location.assign(selectCase(window.location, escape(this.value)));" %>
<%= label :search_case,
          '26-35 mm',
          class: 'menu_item__block_item', for: "search_case_26-35_mm" %>
```

My script to filter the product when it changes the filter option will add the URL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectBrand(path, brand) {
    var p = path.toString();

    p = p.replace(/&search_brand=.+/, "");

    if (p.search("\\?") == -1) {
        p = p + "?";
    }

    p = p + "&search_brand=" + brand;

    return p;
}
function selectCase(path, caseSize) {
   var p = path.toString();

   p = p.replace(/&search_case=.+/, "");

   if (p.search("\\?") == -1) {
     p = p + "?";
   }

   p = p + "&search_case=" + caseSize;

   return p;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `if !params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false` doesn't make sense, can you explain what you're trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

1. strange line of code: `if !params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false`

To show what you are doing, I hacked following code into irb:

```
2.5.0 :001 > params = {case_size: '26-35 mm'}
=> {:case_size=>"26-35 mm"}
2.5.0 :002 > puts 'yes' if !params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false
yes
=> nil
2.5.0 :003 > params = {case_size: 'all'}
=> {:case_size=>"all"}
2.5.0 :004 > puts 'yes' if !params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false
yes
=> nil
2.5.0 :005 > params = {case_size: nil}
=> {:case_size=>nil}
2.5.0 :006 > puts 'yes' if !params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false
=> nil
```

To step you a little more through the code: `!params[:case_size] == "26-35 mm".nil? ? true : false` you can replace by: `!params[:case_size] == false ? true : false` (since a static string never is nil) you could replace by: `params[:case_size] ? true : false` what even is redundant, since params[:case_size] already acts as truthy in every case it is not nil or false. So you just test if params[:case_size] is not nil (or false) in a quite complicated way.
  But you are not even using it as a guard and you do not store the outcome in any variable. So I am quite sure, intention here was to test something and you forgot to cleanup afterwards. It looks more similar to code you want to have in the view for having radio buttons checked or something similar.

2. `@products = @products.where("brand ILIKE '%#{params[:search_brand]}%'")`

   Please never do something alike. You are opening for SQl injection here. I think you wanted something alike: `@products = @products.where('brand LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search_brand]}%")`
   This way rails ensures for securing against sql injections!
3. `if params[:search_case] == "all"
   @products = @products.where(case_size: 0..Float::INFINITY)
   end`
   This looks kind of useless at all. You are only filtering out negative case_size. I think you should validate instead, that case_size is never negative. You will not need this condition, since you want to allow here all.

So in the end I assume, your controller maybe should look alike:

```
@products = @products.order('created_at ASC')
if params[:search_brand].present?
  @products = @products.where('brand LIKE ?',"%#{params[:search_brand]}%")
end
if params[:search_case] == "26-35 mm"
  @products = @products.where(case_size: 26..35)
end
```

If you now want to check, if the sql is correct - include pry or something similar, set a `binding.pry` after this line and check:

```
@products.to_sql
```

Then you will get something alike: `"SELECT \"products\".* FROM \"products\" WHERE \"products\".\"case_size\" BETWEEN '26' AND '35') ORDER BY created_at ASC"
This sometimes just helps very good to check, if the sql query is really what you want to get.

I hope my answer helps you to get deeper into coding rails. Although I see more potential to improve the code further.